# How to show Images from google drive in android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, google-drive-api

I have a 100 images in googledrive and i want to show that images in recyclerview list in android application.
Iam only able to show one image with that specific url
Pls Help

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: so what you have done for this ? please explain some your code you have already try.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to render images from url in a recycler view right?
My approach would be using Glide or Picasso.
Glide can help you load images from a url into your imageview. Using the following line.

```
Glide.with(holder.itemView).load(item.getPicture()).into(ImageViewId)
```

With a recycler view the approach would be that your recycler adapter bind function in your RecyclerView.ViewHolder binds the item's image url to the item's view. All you have to do is bind an array of your image url's to the recycler view's adapter.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your answer. thats not what i want.i want to get images from 'google drive' in android recyclerview.

Comment: Ohh ok. Why don't you use the google drive sdk for that?
It can allow you to get files/images on signed in user's drive.
Or if you only want YOUR drive images to load. Then simply use your own client secret key. Google drive will also give you urls of the images. And you can simply integrate those urls in your recycler view.
Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your help could you please give me suggestions or code snippet etc

Comment: Yess sure. Why don't you check out this tutorial?
This should solve your issue: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5144-integrating-google-drive-in-android

Comment: You can also use the drive REST api. Checkout this link: https://ammar.lanui.online/integrate-google-drive-rest-api-on-android-app-bc4ddbd90820